# Using sameAs in virtuoso sparql between multiple graphs

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl, virtuoso

I am using virtuoso 7.2.1 and i am trying to run a sparql query between 3 graphs.

G1 contains:

```
@prefix : <http://test#> .
:bob :hasAddress :add1 .
```

G2 contains:

```
@prefix : <http://test#> .
:bob :hasAddress :add2 .
```

and G3 contains:

```
@prefix : <http://test#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
:add1 owl:sameAs :add2 .
```

The sparql i'm  trying to run in virtuoso is:

```
DEFINE input:same-as "yes"
Select *
from <http://G1>
from <http://G3>
Where{
<http://test#bob> <http://test#hasAddress> ?z .
}
```

result:

```
<http://test#add1>
```

expected result:

```
<http://test#add1>
<http://test#add2>
```

Note: If i use a **single graph**(G1,G2,G3 merged to G graph) i get the expected result. Why this doesnt work with multiple graphs.
Thanks.

-----------------------------------EDIT--------------

Respectively this query:

```
DEFINE input:same-as "yes"
Select *
from <http://G2>
from <http://G3>
Where{
<http://test#bob> <http://test#hasAddress> ?z .
}
```

or this query:

```
DEFINE input:same-as "yes"
Select ?z
from named <http://G2>
from named <http://G3>
Where{
graph ?g {<http://test#bob> <http://test#hasAddress> ?z .}
}
```

has only this result:

```
<http://test#add2>
```

Comment: It Seems like the Graphs in From clause dont merge correctly ? Or i am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're excluding G2 from your original query, and G1 from your second and third queries.  `sameAs` doesn't add a `FROM` clause to your query; it just says "these two URIs reference the same entity."

Try these --

```
DEFINE  input:same-as  "yes"
SELECT  *
  FROM  <http://G1>
  FROM  <http://G2>
  FROM  <http://G3>
 WHERE 
   {
     <http://test#bob>  <http://test#hasAddress>  ?z 
   }
```

-- and --

```
DEFINE  input:same-as  "yes"
SELECT  *
  FROM  <http://G1>
  FROM  <http://G2>
  FROM  <http://G3>
 WHERE
   {
     <http://test#bob>  <http://test#hasAddress>  ?z 
   }
```

-- and --

```
DEFINE  input:same-as  "yes"
SELECT  ?z
  FROM  NAMED <http://G1>
  FROM  NAMED <http://G2>
  FROM  NAMED <http://G3>
 WHERE
   {
     GRAPH  ?g 
       {  <http://test#bob>  <http://test#hasAddress>  ?z  }
   }
```

Comment: Yeah with my queries i was missing the triple i wanted.   Since as you said sameAs only adds a reference not the triple itself.
I wanted to check sameAs between multiple graphs but this was a failed attempt cause we can also remove G3 graph and still get the desired results i wanted.
Thanks for the answer.